# Why is this div scrollable when the height is calculated based on other elements

Tags: html, css

I wonder why I am able to scroll this setup up and down (without content in it). I do not want to have it scrollable. I expect the height to perfectly fit the screen size. I assume there is something wrong with the `height` of `.page-wrapper-container`, but I am not sure what?

```css
:root {
  --spacer-large: 10px;
  --footer-height: 40px;
  --navigation-height: 80px;
}

body {
    margin: 0
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#root {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper-container {
    height: calc(100% - var(--navigation-height) - var(--footer-height));
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

.page-wrapper-main {
    margin-top: var(--navigation-height);
    margin-bottom: var(--footer-height);
    padding: var(--spacer-large);
    width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--spacer-large));
    height: calc(100% - 2 * var(--spacer-large));
    background-color: green;
}

.navigation-container {
    height: var(--navigation-height);
    background-color: hotpink;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.footer-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
    height: var(--footer-height);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="page-wrapper-container">
  <nav class="navigation-container"></nav>
  <main class="page-wrapper-main"></main>
  <footer class="footer-container"></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: default body margin + the margin-top of page-wrapper-main

Comment: @TemaniAfif if I remove the `margin-top` of `page-wrapper-main` it moves behind the navigation.

Comment: use padding-top on the container instead

Comment: @TemaniAfif that solves it. Would you care to explain why this helps?

Comment: see the duplicates to understand why